# Re-enable System theme file within a child theme

Tags: theming, 8

I have the bootstrap theme installed.

I have a custom theme installed.

The bootstrap.info.yml file has the lines:

```
libraries-override:

# Remove individual stylesheets.
  system/base:
    css:
      component:
        css/components/ajax-progress.module.css: false
        css/components/autocomplete-loading.module.css: false
        css/components/tabledrag.module.css: false
```

In my custom_theme.info.yml file, how can I re-enable the ajax-progress.module.css file?

I've tried adding the following, thinking it would override it, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
libraries-override:

# Re-enable individual stylesheets.
  system/base:
    css:
      component:
        css/components/ajax-progress.module.css: true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of getting this to work is to add the CSS file as a part of your global-styling in `custom_theme.libraries.yml`

```
global-styling:
  css:
    theme:
      /core/modules/system/css/components/ajax-progress.module.css: {}
```

Hope this helps anyone who has come across this problem.